# Correct Twig ternary statement filter?

Tags: twig

I'm attempting to display a href in a ternary statement in Twig, which works using a standard if else statement like the following:

```
{% if news_count|length > 0 %}
    <a href="/{{profile.profile_id}}/news/">News {{news_count}}</a>
{% else %}
    News 0
{% endif %}
```

When attempting to use a ternary statement as follows, I can't get the link to format correctly.

```
{{ (news_count|length > 0) ? '<a href="/' ~ profile.profile_id ~ '/news/">News ' ~ news_count ~ '</a>' : "News 0" }}
```

This prints:

```
<a href="/10/news/">News 25</a> News 25
```

I've tried using the escape and raw filters at the end of the href value, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
{{ ((news_count|length > 0) ? '<a href="/' ~ profile.profile_id ~ '/news/">News ' ~ news_count ~ '</a>' : "News 0")|raw }}
```

BTW it seems that news_count is a int value already. so i assume "|length" isnt needed.